# position div from top based on lower left corner

Tags: javascript, jquery, position

I have some div's in my page that get a transformation applied via panzoom script. I do need to change the height of these divs vith javascript/jquery , and then reposition them in such a way that the lower left corner of the divs remains in the same position and the upper left corner goes up. What I tried is to position them from the top and then removing the height of the div, so that the position is offset().top-DIVHEIGHT. Unfortnuantely due to the transformation and the zooming the position is not as precise as i would need it to be, and when you zoom you see it is off. A better solution would be to give the position of the lower left corner, so I would not have to change its position on resizing. Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can give it `position: fixed`, `bottom: 0;` and `left: 0`, and `width` and `height` as needed.

This will fix it to the lower left corner, or if you change the values for `bottom` and `left`, keep it constant in relation to the lower left corner. To make it responsive, you can use percentage or `vh` and `vw` values for `bottom`, `left`, `width` and `height`.

If you don't mean the lower left corner of the window, but of the `body` or a `div` , you can do the same with `position: absolute`, with the "anchor" element having `position: relative` to serve as the reference for the position.